# Unable to add service reference - visual studio 2015 update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I right click references in a new project all I get is the option to "Add  Connected Service", which then leads to a whole bunch of services that I don't care to use at the moment.  This behaviour is for all project types, class, windows forms, asp.net.

Below is a dump of my install.

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Enterprise

Visual Basic 2015   00322-90000-47835-AA339
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-90000-47835-AA339
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-90000-47835-AA339
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Visual F# 2015   00322-90000-47835-AA339
Microsoft Visual F# 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   5.2.60328.3
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)   14.1.20203.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v2.7.1   14.0.11112.0
Azure App Service Tools v2.7.1

Common Azure Tools   1.7
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0
A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1 EAP 7   Build 105.0.20160319.101702-eap7
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2016 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.1
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

ServiceStackVS   1.0
Templates and tools for use with the ServiceStack framework.

TypeScript   1.8.29.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

I've tried **devenv /resetsettings** but still no luck.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `/resetsettings` is not going to help, it's merely resetting the Visual Studio preferences (.vssettings).

Typically, assuming the installation is intact, this could be fixed by running `devenv /setup` from an elevated prompt. This forces Visual Studio to completely rebuild its caches, so it re-registers all components. Hopefully, after running `/setup`, your environment would go back to normal.

If that doesn't help, I would recommend performing a repair-install of Visual Studio.

Comment: /setup didn't do it either.... on to repair... BTW, thanks for taking the time and effort to answer on a weekend.

Comment: Turns out that Mads used some guys utility to create a script to remove certain items he never used...I have (had) his script installed ...https://gist.github.com/madskristensen/ef64f0809302ea7a289f